# Getting the type of an array member from another type?

Tags: typescript

(I'm having difficulty formulating the question correctly, I haven't found an answer elsewhere)

See below example:

```
export interface MasterProps {
  objects?: Array<{chart: ChartOpts} | {image: ImageOpts}>
}
```

I cannot touch the above definitions.

Now, I know I can get the type of the `objects` property by doing this:

```
   let obj: MasterProps['objects']
```

This will type obj as `Array<{chart: IChartOpts} | {image: ImageProps}>`

But how can I assign obj the type `{chart: IChartOpts} | {image: ImageProps}`?

Answer (score 0):

separate the `object` type on its own and then you can make like this:

```
type obj = {
 chart: IChartOpts
} | {
 image: ImageProps
}
```

and then you can extract it easily like this:

```
export interface MasterProps {
  objects?: Array<obj>
}
let obj:obj
```

Comment: Thank you, but like I said, I can't touch the definition itself (for various reasons)